# Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found

Tags: php, sqlite

So I get the following...

> 172.18.0.1:34548 [500]: /createDatabase.php - Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/createDatabase.php:12
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/runner/Yellow-Pages/createDatabase.php on line 12

the code for createDatabase.php is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home </title>
</head>
<body>
    Home page
    <br>
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>

    <?php

    $db = new SQLite3('phonebook.db', 0666);

    $db ->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonebook( name varchar(30), category varchar(10), number1 varchar(20))')


        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions? I am lost and tried to follow online and docs tutorials but it doesn't work on replit.com

Comment: Did you ask perlit.com this question. It sounds like that php extension is not enables on their environment

Comment: You know what... That is a valid point